# Как использовать сразу несколько lua скриптов с++

Tags: c++, lua

Как можно реализовать использование сразу нескольких луа скриптов, которые не буду друг с другом конфликтовать, использую LuaBridge (с++). Пример кода, как я собираюсь использовать:

```
Lua_class lua("script.lua");
lua.run();
Lua_class lua2("script.lua");
lua2.run();
//Потом что бы можно было спокойно использовать 
lua.run();
```

P.S. я полагаю что надо использовать lua_newthread()

Comment: Что сейчас мешает использовать такой код?

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от реализации вашего `Lua_class`, но что-то мне подсказывает, что там всё сделано правильно и вам совершенно не о чем волноваться. Т.е. в вашем примере всё будет работать так как вы и ожидаете и скрипты не будут мешать друг другу.

Lua разрабатывался с учётом такого паттерна использования и поэтому не имеет глобальных переменных или общих данных и каждый вызов [`luaL_newstate`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_newstate) возвращает изолированное окружение, в котором можно выполнять скрипты. А `lua_newthread()` это совсем не про то.

Comment: Спасибо, просто по названию функции new thread я подумал что это позволяет создавать новый не зависимый поток и это меня запутало ...